# Debugging PHP ADODB.Connection

Tags: php, com, adodb

I am having a trouble to connect to MS SQL2000 with PHP through [COM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php) library.
The message I am getting is:

> Could not establish a database connection exception 'com_exception'
>   with message 'Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
>   Description: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBMSLPCN]SQL Server
>   does not exist or access denied.....

I have read through many posts and couldn't find any straight forward sample how to setup PHP in order to connect easily. These are the steps I've taken so far:

1) running MSSQL2000 with TCP/IP and Named Pipes enabled, listening on port 1433
2) installed PHP Version 5.4.16 TS
3) I have the following extensions enabled (related to mssql):

```
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll
extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
```

4) I have checked for the [COM windows permissions](http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/venkatesan20030501.php3?page=6)
5) I am sure I have provided the correct database/instance, username, password for the connection string.
6) when I instantiate the COM object with:

```
$connection = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
print_r($connection);
```

...I get the **"com Object"** output response, meaning the class seems to work fine.

What have I overlooked ? I have to connect through ADODB since the whole site I am working on is build on it. Is there a way to debug this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED!**

After a few days of figuring this out and reinstalling virtually everything including Apache, different PHP and MSSQL versions I have come up with the following. I am not claiming this to be the best solution but it works:

**Functional environment:**

**1) Windows Azure Server with MSSQL 2012**

**2) Apache 2.2 PHP 5.3.28** - installer: php-5.3.28-Win32-VC9-x86.msi downloaded from:
   http://windows.php.net/download/

**PHP Extensions** (I am listing all but you need just the last few):

```
[PHP_BZ2]
extension=php_bz2.dll
[PHP_CURL]
extension=php_curl.dll
[PHP_ENCHANT]
extension=php_enchant.dll
[PHP_FILEINFO]
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
[PHP_GD2]
extension=php_gd2.dll
[PHP_GETTEXT]
extension=php_gettext.dll
[PHP_GMP]
extension=php_gmp.dll
[PHP_IMAP]
extension=php_imap.dll
[PHP_INTL]
extension=php_intl.dll
[PHP_LDAP]
extension=php_ldap.dll
[PHP_MBSTRING]
extension=php_mbstring.dll
[PHP_MYSQL]
extension=php_mysql.dll
[PHP_MYSQLI]
extension=php_mysqli.dll
[PHP_OCI8]
extension=php_oci8.dll
[PHP_OCI8_11G]
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll
[PHP_OPENSSL]
extension=php_openssl.dll
[PHP_PDO_MYSQL]
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
[PHP_PDO_OCI]
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
[PHP_PDO_ODBC]
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
[PHP_PDO_PGSQL]
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
[PHP_PDO_SQLITE]
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
[PHP_PGSQL]
extension=php_pgsql.dll
[PHP_SHMOP]
extension=php_shmop.dll
[PHP_SNMP]
extension=php_snmp.dll
[PHP_SOAP]
extension=php_soap.dll
[PHP_SOCKETS]
extension=php_sockets.dll
[PHP_SQLITE]
extension=php_sqlite.dll
[PHP_SQLITE3]
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
[PHP_SYBASE_CT]
extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
[PHP_TIDY]
extension=php_tidy.dll
[PHP_XMLRPC]
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
[PHP_XSL]
extension=php_xsl.dll
[PHP_EXIF]
extension=php_exif.dll

php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

**The php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll extension pack was downloaded from:** http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

**The extension=php_com_dotnet.dll downloaded from:** http://originaldll.com/file/php_com_dotnet.dll/29343.html (cannot verify how secure this file is but it works)

**The MSSQL 2012 needs to be set as follows:**

when creating your database, open the management studio and right click the database instance in the left tree. Make sure that under the **properties->security** tab you select: **"SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode"**. Without this you will never connect if you are using the standard username / password method.

Then proceed with creating the database schema and under the main security tab create the new user with username/password related to this database. Make sure you set all permission right i.e: *owner, datareader, datawriter*.

**The PHP connection script I used is as follows:**
**===============================================**

```
function openConnection() { 

        $dbaseServer = "instance name";
        $dbaseIp = "127.0.0.1";
        $dbasePort = "1433";
        $dbaseName = "databsse name";
        $dbaseUser = "username";
        $dbasePassword = "password";                

        $connectionString = ""
        ."Driver={SQL Server};"
        ."Network=DBMSSOCN;"
        ."Server=$dbaseServer;"
        ."Address=$dbaseIp:$dbasePort;"
        ."Database=$dbaseName;"
        ."Uid=$dbaseUser;"
        ."Pwd=$dbasePassword";


    try {

        $connection = new COM("ADODB.Connection");      
        $connection->ConnectionTimeout = 60;
        $connection->Open($connectionString);

        return $connection;

    } catch (exception $e) {

            echo "Could not connect - $e";
            exit;

    }

}

// test query
//===========

$sql = "SELECT * FROM [dbname].[dbo].[tablename]";

        $connection = openConnection();

            // unnecessary but in my case more time is needed.      
        $connection->CommandTimeout = 240;

        $recordset = $connection->Execute($sql);

        if (!$recordset) { $connection->Close(); die("Request failed!"); }

        if (!$recordset->EOF) {

                while (!$recordset->EOF) {

                $test[] = $recordset[0]->value;             

                $recordset->MoveNext();

                }

        }

    print_r($test);

    $connection->Close();
```

--

**I think that's it. Please feel free to correct my post and/or improve it :)**